# Parameter of Oracle Reports with Query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad, oraclereports

I have a query in which get some parameters now I have some entries with org_id and some entries without org_id but when I run this query it is not showing data that has no org_id I just want to run query if data has org_id or not. Query is here

```
SELECT ii.item_desc,
         II.ITEM_CODE,
         ii.uom,
         TO_CHAR (ISL.TRAN_DATE, 'Mon-rr') month,
         TO_CHAR (ISL.TRAN_DATE, 'rr-mm') mon,
         MONTHS_BETWEEN
       (TO_DATE(:edate),
      TO_DATE(:sdate) ) Months,
         ABS (SUM (isl.qty)) qty
    FROM inv_stock_ledger isl, inv_items ii
   WHERE     isl.item_id = II.ITEM_ID
         AND ISL.TRAN_TYPE IN ('SIN', 'SRN', 'STN')
         and II.IS_ACTIVE = 'Y'
         AND ISL.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '01-jan-20' AND '31-may-20'
         AND isl.item_id = NVL ( :item, isl.item_id)
         AND isl.company_id = NVL ( :comp, isl.company_id)
         AND isl.branch_id = NVL ( :branch, isl.branch_id)
         AND isl.store_id = NVL ( :store, isl.store_id)
         AND II.ITEM_CATEGORY_ID = NVL( :VAL_ID, II.ITEM_CATEGORY_ID)
         AND isl.ORG_ID = NVL ( :dept, isl.ORG_ID)
GROUP BY ii.item_desc,
         II.ITEM_CODE,
         ii.uom,
         TO_CHAR (ISL.TRAN_DATE, 'Mon-rr'),
         TO_CHAR (ISL.TRAN_DATE, 'rr-mm')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR (ISL.TRAN_DATE, 'rr-mm'), II.ITEM_DESC asc
```

Comment: maybe something along the lines of `OR isl.ORG_ID IS NULL` as well as `:dept IS NULL` making sure the parentheses are placed accordingly. And you might want to use ANSI JOIN syntax in the query too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, it is `isl.org_id` that has value in some rows, and is `NULL` in others.

If that's so, your

```
AND isl.ORG_ID = NVL ( :dept, isl.ORG_ID)
```

takes care about the `:dept` parameter being null, not the other way round. Should probably be something like this (presuming that ID's datatype is number):

```
and nvl(isl.org_id, -1) = nvl(:dept, -1)
```

Comment: I suggest you create a new question; this one is *solved*.